# g++ (tdm-1) 4.7.1 doesnt support all c++11 features

Tags: c++11, g++-4.7, tdm-mingw

it's supposed g++ (tdm-1) 4.7.1 that comes with codeblocks for windows support all C++11 features, `std::stoi(str)` isnt reconized, same for other c++11 functions. (string header is included).

Do i need to look for another compiler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to missing C library functions in MinGW, see the last few comments on https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37522

I made some improvements so it is supported in MinGW GCC 4.9 and later, so you could just upgrade to a later TDM build.

Comment: where can i download the official MinGW GCC 4.9 ?

Comment: @HelloWorld, that patch breaks code, the change I committed is much simpler and safer and could be applied to the GCC 4.7 header: https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_9-branch/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h?r1=223840&r2=223839&pathrev=223840

Comment: @Cfun, did you try mingw.org?